# What is called after onConfigurationchanged() method

Tags: java, android, onconfigurationchanged

After screen rotating, the height of one of view object is changed, I want to know the height value in pixel.

The `onConfigurationChanged` method is likely called before view finishing rotation. So if I measure the view size in this method , the size is still the value of rotation before.

The problem is how can I get the view size value after rotation finish Without reconstructing  Activity.

Comment: You can always check this in the `OnResume()` method, since it's called after the rotation.

Comment: thank for your answer.It seems does not run OnResume()method since I use        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in AndroidManifest.xml file. I set the breakpoint in OnResume ,but didnot stop when ratation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
private int viewHeight = 0;
View view = findViewByID(R.id.idOfTheView);
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
    new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            viewHeight = view.getHeight();
        }
```

OR

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  int viewHeight = 0;
  View view = findViewByID(R.id.idOfTheView);
  viewHeight  = view.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think the onResume() won't run since I set **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** in AndroidManifest.xml file. I will study the way of OnGlobalLayoutListener.

Comment: `OnResume()` is always called when these's an orientation change, because the whole Activity gets re-created.

Comment: I just read the programming guide article about rotation again. It said that above the API level 12 , configuration change does not restart your activity,
the reference’s address is  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html
in this article there is a paragraph like this

Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged(). ......

Comment: thanks ,the problem is solved by adding GlobalLayoutListener.