# Getting getLineCount() to work when screen is rotated

Tags: android, orientation

I have a line counter for the user in my notepad app. However, when the app is in landscape vs portrait, the amount of text in the `EditText` takes up less space, thus, less lines; so the line count has to update when rotated.

Here is what I did to solve that problem:

I added the following method to my class, and I added this to my activity in my manifest: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

I've tested it and it is going through the method when the screen is rotated.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    TextView linesDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.linesDisplay);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    editText.setText("" + editText.getText().toString()); // this was just a test to see if the Edit Text needed to be "internally constructed"
    linesDisplay.setText("Lines: " + editText.getLineCount());

}
```

I wrote 5 lines in portrait, and it displayed "Lines: 5" just fine. Then, when I rotated to landscape, it stayed at "Lines: 5" (when it was actually 4 lines on landscape). Rotated again back to portrait, now it went to "Lines: 4". Again, back to landscape, it went to "Lines: 5".

It seems that every time I rotate, it displays the number of lines in the orientation **before** it. That is, it will display portrait # of lines when rotated to landscape, then landscapes # of lines when rotated back to portrait, and so on.

P --> "Lines: 5" (correct) 
L --> "Lines: 5" (should be 4) 
P --> "Lines: 4" (should be 5) 
L --> "Lines: 5" (should be 4) 
...

^ it works the same vice versa, like if I start in landscape and keep rotating back it forth, it will be one behind (after the first rotation), just like the situation above.

Any help? I assume it's because it's running through my code before it *actually* rotates, so the line count is behind what it should be. Is there any way to run my code after it's **sure** that the screen is fully rotated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your `onCreate` method:

```
final View view = findViewById(R.id.idOfView);
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() 
    {
        TextView linesDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.linesDisplay);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        linesDisplay.setText("Lines: " + editText.getLineCount());
    }
});
```

And in your `XML`:

In your parent layout properties, add this: `android:id="@+id/idOfView"`

So for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/idOfView"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- widgets -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

or this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/idOfView"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- widgets -->
</LinearLayout>
```

[partial reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876087/what-is-called-after-onconfigurationchanged-method)